# Skype не подтягивает мета тег og:image

Tags: html, skype, opengraph

Проблема описана в заголовке. В html все мета-теги есть:

```
       <meta property="og:title" content="SMART PROMOTION" >
       <meta property="og:description" content="рекламно-сувенирная продукция. промо-текстиль" >
       <meta property="og:url" content="http://smartpromotion.test-domain1.in.ua/" >
       <meta property="og:image" content="http://smartpromotion.test-domain1.in.ua/image/cache/catalog/Smartlogo2020-300x300.png" >
       <meta property="og:image:width" content="300" >
       <meta property="og:image:height" content="300" >
       <meta property="og:site_name" content="SMART PROMOTION - рекламно-сувенирная продукция" >
       <meta property="og:type" content="website"  >
```

В Viber подтягивается изображение, а в Skype - Только title и description. Подскажите, с чем это может быть связано? Возможно, Skype кеширует мета-теги для ссылок? Раннее кидалась ссылка без прописанных мета-тегов. Если да, то можно ли как-то сбросить кэш?

Ссылка на страницу: http://smartpromotion.test-domain1.in.ua/

С других страниц, например, страницы товара мета-теги, включая og:image, подтягиваются нормально (http://smartpromotion.test-domain1.in.ua/index.php?route=product/product&path=233_238&product_id=4111)

Заранее спасибо!

---

Если пересылаю ссылку на главную страницу вида http://smartpromotion.test-domain1.in.ua/index.php?route=common/home, то Skype подтягивает мета-теги, включая изображение, нормально. Видимо дело в кэше и остается только ждать, когда он обновится.